# Shortcodes Keep Wrapping in <p></p>

Tags: shortcode

I've been ripping my hair out for hours and now I'm almost bald! :p Any time I try to insert any shortcode into the visual editor (on its own line), it wraps them in `<p></p>` tags. This happens when I save or switch to the text tab, even after I've manually removed the `<p></p>` tags. Wordpress is basically treating everything as text. It affects both default WP shortcodes and custom ones. Examples:

```
[gallery] -> <p>[gallery]</p>    
[cardimg][/cardimg] -> <p>[cardimg][/cardimg]</p>
[W][/W] -> <p>[W][/W]</p>
```

I have tried every single solution here and on Google: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=shortcode+wrap I don't know what to do at this point. Absolutely nothing I do changes the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/

It basically removes any `p`-tags before and after `[` or `]`, before rendering the content.

So the output of your shortcodes won't be wrapped in `p`-tags

Comment: but why does this happen at the first place?

Comment: Wordpress `the_content` filter utilizes this function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/